# IVT for $a(x) = x+2+\frac{|x-2|}{x-2}$

Tags: calculus

If we have the function $a(x) = x+2 + \frac{|x-2|}{x-2}$, where $x$ is a member of $[1,5]$ and $y$ is a member of $[2,8]$, when we apply the Intermediate Value Theorem, why could it be either true or false?

Answer (score 1):

$a(x) = 2 + x + \frac{|x-2|}{x-2}$ is not continuous on $[1,5]$ because it is not defined at $x=2$.  In fact $\lim_{x \to 2^-}a(x)=3, \lim_{x \to 2^+}a(x)=5$.  You therefore do not have the hypotheses of the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\dfrac{|x-2|}{x-2}$ is equal to $-1$ if $x<2$ and equal to $1$ if $x>2$, so there's a jump discontinuity, and jump discontinuities are exactly what the intermediate value theorem says will not be there, **if** the function is continuous.

Comment: In that case, why is the IVT always true for the function $b(x) = 2+x - \frac{|x-2|}{x-2}$, where x is a member of $[1, 5]$ and y is a member of $[b(1), b(5)]$ even with the discontinuity at $x=2$? b(x) is slightly different than the a(x) I posted in my original question.

Comment: @Stuck: graphs are your friend.  Graph $b(x)$ and see what you get.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang When I graph it, I still seem to see another jump discontinuity like in a(x). What is the difference?

Comment: ok, I neglected the fact that you changed plus to minus.  The image of $[1,2)$ under $b$ is $[3,4)$, and the image of $(2,5]$ is $(3,6]$, so the image of $[1,2)\cup(2,5]$ is $[3,4)\cup(3,6] = [3,6]$.  Thus the entire interval from $3$ to $6$ is included in the image of $b$, so the conclusion of the mean value theorem does apply to $b$.  But not to $a$ since the image of $[1,2)\cup(2,5]$ under $a$ is $[2,3) \cup (5,8]$, so the conclusion of the IVT is not true of $a$ on the whole interval $[2,5]$. However, there are some subintervals (short intervals about $2$) for which the$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$conclusion of the IVT is NOT true of $a$. $\qquad$

Comment: @Stuck: Michael is right.  This is also consistent with the IVT.  Although the conclusions are satisfied, the hypotheses are not.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Thanks both of you for the help. My last question is about Michael's comment: he says that the image of [1,2) under b is [3,4), but isn't it [4,5)? How would this impact the [3,6] conclusion of b's image if we have f(x) is a member of [4,5) and (3,6] instead?

Comment: @Stuck : Sorry --- you do get $[4,5)\cup(3,6] = (3,6].$  But that is an interval, so the conclusion of the IVT is true on this interval, but fails on some small subintervals. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

The function can be written piecewise as
$$
   f(x) = \begin{cases} x+1 & \text{if $1 ≤ x < 2$} \\
                        x+3 & \text{if $2 < x ≤ 5$} \end{cases}
$$
Notice that $f(2)$ is not defined.
The graph of $f$ is the line segment from $(1,2)$ to $(2,3)$ (not including the latter point), then the line segment from $(2,5)$ to $(5,8)$ (not including the former point).  You might want to draw it for reference.

We have
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x) &= 3 \\
    \lim_{x\to 2^+} f(x) &= 5 
\end{align*}
So $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)$ does not exist.

The IVT requires that $f$ be *continuous* on a closed, bounded interval.  Right now $f$ is defined only on $[1,2)\cup(2,5]$, which is not a single interval (nor is it closed).  What's worse, even if we choose a value for $f(2)$, the fact that $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$ does not exist says that $f$ cannot be continuous at $2$.  So no matter what, we cannot satisfy the hypotheses of the IVT.

You say “why could it be either true or false?”  I am guessing what you mean is that why should the statement “there exists $x$ in $[1,5]$ such that $f(x) = c$” be true for some values of $c$ in $[2,8]$ and false for other values of $c$?  Let's verify it.  Is there an $x$ such that $f(x) = 6$?  Yes, $f(3) = 3+3 = 6$.
Is there an $x$ such that $f(x) = 4$? No, because $x$ is either less than 2 or greater than 2.  If $x < 2$, $f(x) = 4 \implies x+1 = 4 \implies x=3$, which is a contradiction.  If $x>2$, $f(x) = 4 \implies x+3 = 4 \implies x=1$, also a contradiction.  (This is easier to see on a graph; sorry I don't have the time to produce one.)

So there are some values of $c$ which have a corresponding $x$, but some values of $c$ which do not.  The reason this is consistent with the IVT, and not contradicting, it is that $f$ is not continuous.